# Pig multiple store commands creating duplicate work

Tags: performance, apache-pig

I have a pig script which reads input from a file and sends to our custom UDF, which sends back a Map with 2 key/value pair. After that we have to save each key value pair in 2 different locations. We are doing it using Store. Problem we are facing is each STORE command which we are using in our pig script is invoking our custom UDF.

```
>REGISTER MyUDF.jar;

>LOADFILE = LOAD '$file' AS record:chararray;
>MAPREC = FOREACH LOADFILE GENERATE MyUDF(record);
>ERRLIST = FOREACH MAPREC {
>GENERATE $0#'errorRecord' AS ErrorRecord;
>};
>ERRLIST = FILTER ERRLIST BY ErrorRecord is not null;

>MLIST = FOREACH MAPREC {
>GENERATE $0#'mInfo' AS MRecord;
>};
>MLIST = FILTER MLIST BY MRecord is not null;

>STORE MLIST INTO 'fileOut';
>STORE ERRLIST INTO 'errorDir';
```

Is there a way in pig script through which UDF will be invoked only once, even if we have multiple STORE....

Answer (score 0):

I think that what's happening under the covers is that MAPREC isn't populated by its assignment statement.  Pig is waiting until MAPREC is used (which is twice)  to figure out what it contains.  I suggest creating an intermediate structure by using a FOREACH to iterate over MAPREC.  That would force the calling of MyUDF once and then use that intermediate result twice in place of MAPREC in the following FOREACH statements.  Hope that made sense.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your input. We will try it. But when we use Pig 'Explain' it shows two Map reduce plans each for 2 STORE commands as in pig script....this made me think that the way how we are extacting/using pig relations might be wrong...Any inputs on this

Comment: Right.  I would expect to see to mapreduce steps for the two stores since under the covers STORE UDF's interact with OutputFormat classes and there's usually one OutputFormat per reducer.

Comment: Pig doesn't step through the script executing line by line.  Instead it steps through building up formulas (for lack of a better word) for each of the "variables" in assignment statements.  I don't know how Pig decides when to actually kick off a mapreduce step, but in your case it's waiting too long.  What I'm proposing will hopefully trigger yet another mapreduce step earlier in the processing.

Comment: Chris problem is different. We are not executing the above pig script in grunt shell but running through PigServer. If we run in grunt shell only one map reduce plan is done and working as expected. PigServer by default is not executing in Multi Query Mode. So what we have done is pigServer.setBatchOn();pigServer.registerFile('pigFile');pigServer.executeBatch(); These changes worked. Thanks